# Android Lifecycle: Is onResume() supposed to be called during startup?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I'm trying an example from **Android Application Development for Dummies**, which is a simple app that toggles the ringing mode of the phone. The code is below.

```
public class SilentModeToggleActivity extends Activity {

  private AudioManager mAudioManager;
  private boolean mPhoneIsSilent;

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    checkIfPhoneIsSilent();
    setButtonClickListener();
  }

  @Override public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkIfPhoneIsSilent();
    toggleUi();
  }

  private void checkIfPhoneIsSilent() {
    int ringerMode = mAudioManager.getRingerMode();
    if (ringerMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
      mPhoneIsSilent = true;
    } else {
      mPhoneIsSilent = false;
    }
  }

  private void setButtonClickListener() {
    Button toggleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mPhoneIsSilent) {
          mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
          mPhoneIsSilent = false;
        } else {
          mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
          mPhoneIsSilent = true;
        }
        toggleUi();
      }
    });
  }

  private void toggleUi() {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.phone_icon);
    Drawable newPhoneImage;
    if (mPhoneIsSilent) {
      newPhoneImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_silent);
    } else {
      newPhoneImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_on);
    }
    imageView.setImageDrawable(newPhoneImage);
  }
}
```

My question is since I only override `onCreate()` (shows the "normal" mode image at default) and `onResume()`, it's expected that the image changes to "silent" if I change the phone mode to silent outside the app (in `onResume()` I check the current state and update the UI), but why it still shows the correct image even if I **KILL** the process and then change the phone mode to silent?

I would expect the app to reload and shows the default image, which is normal. Not the correct yet confusing silent image.

Comment: The silent image in this case is confusing because you didn't expect it, but the program is working correctly. I added a link below to the Activity documentation. If you wanted the app to work the way you anticipated remove the call to toggleUi() in onResume(). Then you would start with the default image and only after the button is clicked would you get the 'correct' image.

Comment: try to debug and check..

Answer (score 5):

`onResume()` is called any time an activity is regaining the foreground input. This includes:

- When it is returning to the screen after something else had the foreground (e.g., Settings), and
- When it is being created for the first time in this process (which includes any new process required because you killed the old one from DDMS)

Hence, your code will examine the state of the ringer mode in either case and will use the proper image in either case.

Answer (score 4):

onResume isn't limited to being called after the activity has been paused, it's called *whenever the activity goes to the top* of the activity stack. That includes the first time it's shown after it's been created.

The [developer doucmentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle) is quite detailed about how the actiivty lifecycle works, including a flowchart and table which describes when each lifecycle callback is actually called.

Comment: I read that onCreate should always be followed by onStart, which I didn't include in my code...so it just jumps from onCreate to onResume?

Comment: @user1447343: No, it still calls onStart, but it calls the default implementation found in the base Activity class - this is a very important aspect of inheritance in object-oriented programming. Note that both onResume and onCreate are marked with `@Override`; in simplified terms, that means you're replacing the onResume and onCreate methods of the base class with those found in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find the recent updates to the Android developer documentation will clarify your answer. onResume() will be called anytime your activity starts for the first time, bring the activity to the foreground, or bring the phone out of the lock screen.

[Android Activity Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

onResume IS called at startup. Please refer to the the activity lifecycle documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).