# Why onResume() is called while the app is running?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, onresume

According to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10968942/1973164) by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware):

> `onResume()` is called any time an activity is regaining the foreground
>   input. This includes:
>
> - When it is returning to the screen after something else had the
>     foreground (e.g., Settings), and
> - When it is being created for the first time in this process (which
>     includes any new process required because you killed the old one from
>     DDMS)
>
> Hence, your code will examine the state of the ringer mode in either
>   case and will use the proper image in either case.

But in my case, `onResume()` is being called while the app is running without any of the above conditions. `onResume()` has a `refresh()` method which shows a `ProgressBar`, loads some contents in the `WebView`, and then hides the `ProgressBar` and shows the `WebView`.

Note that it doesn't always happen, but most of the times it does.

I'm really curious to know why this happens, and if possible, how could I prevent it because it is really annoying for the users to see it happen.

Code:

```
public void refresh()
{
        webView.clearCache(true);
        layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fetcher = new DataFetcher();

        String url = "http...." // some url
        fetcher.execute(url);
}

public void onResume()
{
        super.onResume();
        refresh();
}
```

**EDIT**
Here's what I got after `Thread.dumpStack()` (these show twice in logcat, so onResume() is called twice):

```
12-12 10:36:22.033: W/HardwareRenderer(22358): Attempting to initialize hardware acceleration outside of the main thread, aborting
12-12 10:36:24.947: W/HardwareRenderer(22358): Attempting to initialize hardware acceleration outside of the main thread, aborting
12-12 10:36:26.744: W/HardwareRenderer(22358): Attempting to initialize hardware acceleration outside of the main thread, aborting
12-12 10:36:27.064: W/System.err(22358): java.lang.Throwable: stack dump
12-12 10:36:27.088: W/System.err(22358):    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:496)
12-12 10:36:27.088: W/System.err(22358):    at com.example.app.menufragments.SalesByPointsFragment.onResume(SampleFragment.java:101)
12-12 10:36:27.088: W/System.err(22358):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1543)
12-12 10:36:27.088: W/System.err(22358):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:963)
12-12 10:36:27.088: W/System.err(22358):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
12-12 10:36:27.088: W/System.err(22358):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
12-12 10:36:27.088: W/System.err(22358):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1894)
12-12 10:36:27.088: W/System.err(22358):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:466)
12-12 10:36:27.088: W/System.err(22358):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:455)
12-12 10:36:27.088: W/System.err(22358):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onPostResume(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:68)
12-12 10:36:27.088: W/System.err(22358):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5195)
12-12 10:36:27.088: W/System.err(22358):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2860)
12-12 10:36:27.088: W/System.err(22358):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2899)
12-12 10:36:27.088: W/System.err(22358):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
12-12 10:36:27.088: W/System.err(22358):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-12 10:36:27.088: W/System.err(22358):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 10:36:27.088: W/System.err(22358):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
12-12 10:36:27.096: W/System.err(22358):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 10:36:27.096: W/System.err(22358):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 10:36:27.096: W/System.err(22358):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
12-12 10:36:27.096: W/System.err(22358):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
12-12 10:36:27.096: W/System.err(22358):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I also put `Thread.dumpStack()` at `onPause()`, and again the logs start with:

```
12-12 10:55:38.502: W/HardwareRenderer(29996): Attempting to initialize hardware acceleration outside of the main thread, aborting
12-12 10:55:38.572: W/HardwareRenderer(29996): Attempting to initialize hardware acceleration outside of the main thread, aborting
12-12 10:55:46.369: W/HardwareRenderer(29996): Attempting to initialize hardware acceleration outside of the main thread, aborting
12-12 10:55:50.736: W/HardwareRenderer(29996): Attempting to initialize hardware acceleration outside of the main thread, aborting
```

I believe this has to do with the `WebView`, perhaps the *intensive* work makes it pause and resume?

---

Also I get warnings of Choreographer. It all happens because of the `WebView` I believe as it shows javascript charts. Does the `WebView` do it's processing in the main thread?

Comment: Please post your code so that we can understand why this is happening and help you

Comment: I have seen onResume() being called twice (with no onPause()) before. This was with a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.

Comment: I posted some code but I'm not sure if there's more code needed

Comment: @tristan2468 mine is a Samsung Galaxy Nexus

Comment: normally if your app is in the foreground, `onResume()` will not be called. If it is being called then that sounds very strange.

Comment: double onResume? are you sure? Add `Thread.dumpStack();` before super.onResume() to see if there's more than one call.

Comment: @MartínMarconcini I posted the logs after Thread.dumpStack();

Comment: There seems to be only one call to onResume: `at com.example.app.menufragments.SalesByPointsFragment.onResume(SampleFragment.java:101)`, your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @MartínMarconcini I got lost at the logs because of the scroll lock. Actually the dumpStack() is called twice, the logs I posted above show twice in logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small update. Although the activity lifecycle states otherwise, it *was* calling onResume twice. But it happened only when debugging and not normally. So it probably was a bug.

Answer (score 3):

According to the activity lifecycle, it is not possible that it does `onResume()` once it's running, unless it does first `onPause()`.

[image]

Are you pausing the app anyway? Maybe turning off the screen (even automatically)? Or changing between activities? If not, I'd check if you change the ProgressBar and WebView in other parts of your code, it seems the problem is not onResume.

You can always write a `Log.i(tag, string)` and see when it goes to the method.

I wanted to comment instead answering, but I have not enough reputation, sorry.